# Html 5 Android PhoneGap

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. In that, I am trying to get the image in the javascript, but its not loading. Can someone help me to get the image in the javascript in the phone gap android app...

Code:

```
<img src="img/nextIcon.png" /></span>'
```

Answer (score 0):

why the end span tag ?

Basically your file should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Something</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function onLoad() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  }
  function onDeviceReady() {

  }

  </script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">

<img src="img/nextIcon.png" />

</body>
</html>
```

And then of course you should have included the image in a folder called img which is in you www folder